# Radial intercept lengths by a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I'm trying to find a formula for the length of intercepts by a circle, of radial lines passing through a point inside a circle. For example, when the point coincides with the center, it would be equal to r, and when the point lies on the circle, the answer is sin(theta).

Is there a general form equation that can apply to the points inside and outside the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a point at a distance $a$ from center $O$. And let $Q$ be a point on the circle, with $PQ=d$ and $\angle OPQ=\theta$. By the cosine rule applied to triangle POQ we have:
$$
r^2=d^2+a^2-2ad\cos\theta.
$$
From that you can find $d$:
$$
d=a\cos\theta+\sqrt{r^2-a^2\sin^2\theta},
$$
where I chose the sign in front of the square root so that $d=r+a$ for $\theta=0$.

Comment: [+1] ... the last formula being valid iff the quantity inside the radical is  $\geq 0$, i. e.  for a limited range of values of $\theta$ when the point is outside the circle, as awaited.